# PHP SMPP Implementation for SMS Delivery

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway, smpp, bulksms

I am doing PHP SMPP implementation, connecting to [SMS SMPP](http://www.innovativetxt.com/) Provider.  I have found below PHP library to do that.

www.phpclasses.org/package/1373-PHP-Sends-SMS-messages-via-an-SMPP-server.html

I found Good Example here  to send the SMS Messages.

1)  How to Receive the message and receive the delivery reports.

2)  How i can different if its intermediate delivery report or final delivery report and what is status of messages. ?

3) How to differentiate if its incoming message or delivery report? Sorry i am new to SMPP world.

4) Which pard of below i shall consider?

Below is what i get when i call readPDU() function

Bind Transmitter PDU: 73 110 110 111 118 97 116 105 118 101 116 120 116 0 80 64 119 101 98 49 50 51 52 53 0 87 87 87 0 51 0 0 0 Sending PDU, len == 49 Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 2 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 28 bytes. Stream len : 24 Command id : 2. Command status : 0. sequence_number : 1. Got CM_BIND_TRANSMITTER_RESP. system id : OZEKISYSTEM. Received PDU: €(0)(0)(2)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(1)OZEKISYSTEM(0) Sending PDU, len == 16 Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 21 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 16 bytes. Stream len : 12 Command id : 21. Command status : 0. sequence_number : 2. GOT CM_ENQUIRELINK_RESP. Received PDU: €(0)(0)(21)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(2) In split_message. One message: 23 PDU spec: a1cca9cca13ccca1a1ccccca23. Sending PDU, len == 76 Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 4 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 24 bytes. Stream len : 20 Command id : 4. Command status : 0. sequence_number : 3. Got CM_SUBMIT_SM_RESP. message id : 19EE3BF. Received PDU: €(0)(0)(4)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(3)19EE3BF(0) Sending PDU, len == 16 Sending PDU, header-len == 16 Sending PDU, command_id == 6 Trying to read PDU. Reading PDU : 16 bytes. Stream len : 12 Command id : 6. Command status : 0. sequence_number : 4. Got CM_UNBIND_RESP. Received PDU: €(0)(0)(6)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(0)(4)

ANy help will be regarded. ANy body did similar code in past?   H